# Sencha touch 2 how to change button action in run time?

Tags: button, sencha-touch-2, action

Is it possible to change action of button in run time without creating a new button?

I can see from documentation that button doesn't have setter for the action property and it doesn't work if I write `button.action = 'something';`.

Answer (score 0):

We can change action of button in run time without creating a new button
Try this :

Ext.getCmp('button2').setHandler(function(){alert("handler has been changed");});

Comment: Though this actually works it doesn't change the buttons action property for the controller to handle the event properly.

Comment: We have prepared a demo to show how it works, Click on Button1 to change handler for Button2  http://www.nethues.com/sencha/